# Touch slider with multiple layers (left-right, bottom-top)

Tags: jquery, swipe

I've been looking around but i can't this particular type of slider.

I'm looking for a script which is a touch slider (left to right) but also has a text box on the bottom of the picture. If you click on this div, or preferably swipe, this text box should go up towards 50% of the height of the slider (or 100% that doesn't really matter), to show the full text.

It basically means that this slider should support sliding from left to right (top-part, 75%) but the bottom part is a div which lays on top of the slider which should slide up and down (intro text -> full text).

Is there any slider that does this?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, but in all honesty this is a pretty specific need. My recommendation would be to find something that does most of what you need and extend it, or write your own jQuery plugin that handles it.

Comment: My knowledge of jquery is too limited to write my own plugin, so I've been looking at existing touch sliders. However, I can't find a touch slider which has multiple layers. I'm not asking for a specific code, I'm just asking for some directions. I've looked at many companies and many different sliders, but maybe there are some I have overlooked. Also, I couldn't find anything related to this on stackoverflow so I thought the answers here could be beneficial for others as well.